# How to replace last 3 characters in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to replace last three characters with "*", but I do not think I'm doing it okay.
I'll share my code below :

```
//This is the string and is looking like this : 07123456789
var phoneNumber = viewModel.securityAndLoginAssetsData?.userProfile.phones.phoneLogin 
let endIndex = phoneNumber!.index(phoneNumber!.startIndex, offsetBy: -3)
var finalPhoneNumber = phoneNumber!.replaceSubrange(...endIndex, with: "*")
```

This is how I'm trying to display it, but I got this error :
"Type '()' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'"

```
 Text(finalPhoneNumber)
```

What can I do in this case, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and avoid indices and force unwrapping:

```
extension String {
    func replacing(last n: Int, with s: String) -> String {
        let replacement = String(repeating: s, count: min(count, n))
        return dropLast(n) + replacement
    }
}

"123456".replacing(last: 3, with: "*") // 123***
```

Comment: Avoid indices? That’s the proper way when dealing with collections

Comment: Thanks a lot, is working well. About the force unwrapping, I know is not good practice, but I did it only to keep the errors away to post this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory. `finalPhoneNumber` is not a `String` it is a method. This happens because `replaceSubrange` doesn’t return anything. It is a mutating method. What you need is to pass `phoneNumber` instead. Note that you have some other issues in your code like unwrapping `phoneNumber` and offset should be from `endIndex`. I would also pass `starIndex` as the `limitedBy` parameter or use `formIndex` to mutate `endIndex` var which doesnt return an optional and won't pass beyond `startIndex` when offsetting. Something like:

```
if var phoneNumber = viewModel.securityAndLoginAssetsData?.userProfile.phones.phoneLogin {
    var endIndex = phoneNumber.endIndex
    phoneNumber.formIndex(&endIndex, offsetBy: -3, limitedBy: phoneNumber.startIndex)
    phoneNumber.replaceSubrange(endIndex..., with: repeatElement("*", count: min(3, phoneNumber.count)))
}
```